# Touch listener and changing parent

Tags: java, android, drag-and-drop, ontouchlistener, onlongclicklistener

I apologize for my English. I have a problem.
I use a listeners LongClick and TouchListener.

In the long click - the view is removed and the parent view is inserted into the other parent.
Touch stops working, because there was a change parent.

How do I keep TouchListener to View?

```
static boolean drag = false;
static View parent;
static OnLongClickListener olcl = new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        if(!drag) {
            parent = (View) v.getParent();
            int[] loc = {0, 0};
            v.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
            ((ViewGroup) parent).removeView(v);
            Main.mainRelative.addView(v);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            par.leftMargin = loc[0];
            par.topMargin = loc[1];
            v.setLayoutParams(par);

            drag = true;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};

static OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

        if(v.getParent() != null && v.getParent() == Main.mainRelative) {
            //!!!!!!!!!!!!!
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams par = (LayoutParams) v.getLayoutParams();
            par.leftMargin = (int) (event.getRawX() - v.getWidth()/2);
            par.topMargin = (int) (event.getRawY() - v.getHeight()/1.2);
            v.setLayoutParams(par);

            for(int y = 0; y < Main.radioGroupLeftMain.getChildCount(); y++) {
                RadioButton rb = (RadioButton) ((ViewGroup) Main.radioGroupLeftMain.getChildAt(y)).getChildAt(0);
                if(checkHit((int)event.getRawX(), (int)event.getRawY(), rb)) {
                    rb.setChecked(true);
                } else {
                    rb.setChecked(false);
                }

                if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {


                    try { ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v); } catch(Exception e) {};
                    if(v.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                        ((ViewGroup) parent).addView(v);
                    }
                    drag = false;
                }
            }   
        }



        return false;
    }
};

public static boolean checkHit(int x, int y, View v) {
    int[] loc = {0, 0};
    v.getLocationOnScreen(loc);
    Rect rv = new Rect(loc[0], loc[1], loc[0]+v.getWidth(), loc[1]+v.getHeight());


    return rv.contains(x, y);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when your are going to add view **Main.mainRelative.addView(v);**
before this create new View, initialize with this view *v* like **View vv = v**
then again set touch listener **vv.setOnTouchLIstener(ot1);**
try this it should work...

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've tried to do it. This does not work because it does not works ACTION_DOWN

Comment: "does not works ACTION_DOWN" means??
you want click listener or touchlistener or both?

Comment: View has onLongClickListener and onTouchListener. When you first click fires longClick, and TouchListener not work. If you release your finger from the screen and re-apply - work ACTION_DOWN View and start moving your finger

Comment: I'm sorry, ACTION_DOWN work. But after longClick - TouchListener not already running.

Comment: hmm...
can u do one thing...Do your work in ACTION_UP,
suppose if Long click happened then your ACTION_UP will not work in this case u can handle functionality in Long click
you can use one flag variable also....

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I solved my problem by OnDragListener. I tied to the parent onDragListener View and detect all the coordinates of movement. I'll bet you a +1 for your help.